# Find the values of $k$ and $p$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When $kx^{3}+ px^{2}- x+ 3$ is divided by $x- 1,$ the remainder is $4.$
When $kx^{3}+ px^{2}- x+ 3$ is divided by $x- 2,$ the remainder is $21.$
Find the values of $k$ and $p.$
I've been stuck trying to solve this, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does the Polynomial Factor Theorem say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Remainder theorem, when we divide a polynomial $f(x)$ by $x-a$ where $a$ is a constant, the remainder is given by $f(a)$. Now, If $f(x)=kx^3+px^2-x+3$ as stated above, then $f(1)=4$ and $f(2)=21$. Hence we get $k+p+2=4$ and $8k+4p+1=21$. It then follows that $k=3$ and $p=-1$.

Comment: You are new to the website, and so I would like to tell you that it is not **advised** and is certainly **not a good** practice to answer questions, which don't show their work.

Comment: You can see yourself, I and the other user also have given only hints.

Answer (score 1):

The Remainder Theorem states that

> For a polynomial $p(x)$, the remainder when it is divided by $x-a$ for some constant $a$, is equal to $f(a)$.

Can you take it from here?